"Failed to install package" when switching language in KDE
I am using KDE Plasma 5.27.11 on Ubuntu 24.04. I am trying to change the "Time" language from "American English (United States)" to "English (United States)", as I prefer that my system's local uses the YYYY-MM-DD date format.
(apologies for the huge screenshots, my system has 200% DPI scaling and StackExchange made my screenshots big)

However, when I select it (or any other option) and click "Apply", System Settings gives me this error:

The error shows up immediately, it does not give me any password prompt to authenticate.
How do I fix this error? Why did it fail to install the package? Which package? How can I find out which packages I need? Can I install the package manually outside of System Settings? Why can't System Settings install it?
I also get this error if I open the Language switcher:


I don't know the definite answer but here is what I would do to troubleshoot..
Ensure polkit-kde-agent-1 is installed
sudo apt install polkit-kde-agent-1

Ensure pkexec is installed:
sudo apt install pkexec

Try adding locale again trough UI (restart system settings)

If not working then from CLI
# will ask which locales to generate
sudo apt install locales

If the locales package is already installed then:
# Not sure if sudo is required
dpkg-reconfigure locales


All three of those packages are already installed. dpkg-reconfigure locales and selecting locales from the command line allowed me to successfully select it from the GUI. I was still not able to select "English (United States)" but I was at least able to set the time format to "Canadian English (Canada)" which also has the correct time format.

I suggest you choose and set some non English language, ex. German or what ever, and then switch back but to "English (United States)", it's possible there is conflict because same country.
